# while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)) ) vs while (RXC == 0)

Tags: avr, uart

I have question about code below :

```
    unsigned char USART_Recieve(void)
    {
        /* Wait for data to be received*/
        while ( !(UCSRA &  (1<<RXC)));
        /* Get and return received data from buffer*/
        return UDR;
    }
```

Why do we just don't write

```
    while (RXC == 0);
```

when we want to wait until receiving data is done ? and what's the difference? 
and how the first while waits until receiving is done?

I have searched for the same question but i couldn't find any, So please tell me the link.

Thanks.

Comment: This needs more context to answer properly but `RXC` appears to be a bit position, constant,  and `UCSRA` appears to be a register in this particular processors UART..  You are waiting for the bit to change state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do we just don't write
>       while (RXC == 0);

Because "RXC" is a constant 7. Which is the number of the RXC bit in UCSRA register. So, while() will exit immediately, because it is expanded into 
`while (7 == 0);`

Note, that I've given you an example for ATmega32. For different controller "RCX" macro can have different value.

And just in case you are wondering, "UCSRA" and "UDR" in your code are also two macro definitions referencing another macro, _SFR_IO8.

UPDATE

For example, the macros:

```
#define RXC     7
#define UCSRA   _SFR_IO8(0x0B)
```

transform the code `while (!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));` into

```
while (!(_SFR_IO8(0x0B) & 0x80));
```

Then the macro

```
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
```

transforms the code further into

```
while (!(_MMIO_BYTE((0x0B) + __SFR_OFFSET) & 0x80));
```

Since _MMIO_BYTE and __SFR_OFFSET are also macros, the process continues until all macro directives processed. In the end you get yourself a code that reads 
UCSRA register and applies mask for bit #7 in it.

The whole reason for all this is to make code more portable. For example by changing 0x0B in the UCSRA macro we can access UCSRA registers in different controllers without changing register address in our code.

Comment: RXC is the value of RXC bit in UCSRA, right. And when RXC is zero it means that receiver buffer value is just read or the act of receiving is not completed and buffer value is not read yet, So my question is the second while can act just as first while, doesn't it?

Comment: "RXC is the value of RXC bit in UCSRA, right" Wrong. "RCX" is the **number** of RXC bit in a register, not a value of that bit.  Look at the datasheet. UCSRA bits: MCPM is bit number 0, U2X is bit number 1, etc. RXC is bit number 7. "RCX" in your code is a macro, defined as 7.

Comment: Right, I get your point. Thank you for correcting my misunderstanding, That was really confusing for me.

Comment: But you said that UCSRA and UDR are two other macros, So you mean that UCSRA is not related to the value of corresponding register, how it could be? So how can the original while work correctly? I mean that if we suppose UCSRA as the value of corresponding register the while condition become meaningful but otherwise, I think it's meaningless.

Comment: You really have to learn how macro definitions work before declaring it meaningless. See an update in the answer.

Comment: Alright, Thank you very much. But still another question, Can we use the sign UCSRA.7 to reach the value of the port RCX just as PORTX.n ? If so what's the reason to use the first way?

Comment: +1 Good concise answer to a question that vexes many beginners

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using CodeVision? Because PORTX.n syntax is not ANSI-C standard, it is CodeVision own dubious "feature", not portable or transferable anywhere and limited to GPIO registers only. If you want similar functionality in compatible format you can use bitfields: https://www.edaboard.com/entry.php?861-Accessing-individual-PORT-bits-in-AVR-with-avrgcc-(winAVR)

Comment: Yes, I use CodeVision. I didn't know this feature is just available in CodeVision. Thanks a lot.